# OpenCV4android armeabiv7 without NEON support dies with Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL)

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, neon, android

I have an Android application using OpenCV4Android (3.0.0).

It works well on most devices, however on a Samsung Galaxy Tab P7100 it dies at startup with `Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL)`.

The error definitely comes from the OpenCV part, since it does not occur when I do not load the library (via `OpenCVLoader.initDebug()`).

After a lot of googeling I found that the device does not support NEON instructions and think that this is the cause of the error.

Since I do not want to require users to install the OpenCV manager, I added the OpenCV4android as a dependency such that the `libopencv_java3.so` file is copied into the apk and linked. However, it simply copies the file from `libs/armeabi-v7a` to the apk which is built with NEON support.

How can I ensure that devices without NEON support use the armeabi version or an armeabi-v7a version without NEON instructions?

Do you have any other suggestions how I can get the app running on this device?

I am quite new to native libraries on Android, so i might be missing a lot and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a real answer, but the best I could come up with:

I use opencv4android version 2.4.11 now. In this version it works on all devices I tested so far.